# Finding articles under a specific ID using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

[Here is a screenshot of the section I want to web scrape, I took a screenshot because I just wanted to give an overall picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zKkc.png)

Im trying to web scrape a certain section of the BBC site, this is the latest updates section. It looks a bit like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26LoQ.png)

Im not sure what to put for the findAll in Beautifulsoup. Using the knowledge I already have I tried `bsObj.findAll(id="latest-updates")` which of course didn't work. If anyone needs a link of the latest update it would be here https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk and scrolling down gives your the latest update

Im trying to find a way to obtain all the links in the latest update section by using the id perhaps?
If the correct way is using id=latest-updates, could someone point me to what I did wrong - or else if Im completely wrong tell me which class, id or div Im supposed to find the links under this specific latest update I should be looking for.
Sorry if this is too much of a specific question and
Thanks for any help regarding the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the links of the headlines of latest updates, i think you should search for "a" and the class of the headlines. If I'm not wrong, this should be the right findAll:

```
 findAll("a", {"class": "qa-heading-link lx-stream-post__header-link"})
```

Comment: could you explain what 'a' refers to when searching for this.

Comment: "a" is referencing the <a> html tag, which is a link (<a href="path/linked/somewhere.html">text</a>). So the first filter is "all links" and the secound is filtering those with the class of the headlines.